# Given a list of primes and a factorization pattern, how to construct all numbers whose prime factorization matches the given pattern?

Tags: c++, recursion, permutation

Though, I've tried to summarize the question in the title, I think it'll be better if I start off with an instance of the problem:

List of Primes        = {2 3 5 7 11 13}
Factorization pattern = {1 1 2 1}

For the above input, the program should be generating the following list of numbers:

- 2.3.5^2.7
- 2.3.5^2.11
- 2.3.5^2.13
- 2.3.7^2.11
- 2.3.7^2.13
- 2.3.11^2.13
- 2.5.7^2.11
- 2.5.7^2.13
- 2.7.11^2.13
- 3.5.7^2.11
- 3.5.7^2.13
- 3.5.11^2.13
- 3.7.11^2.13
- 5.7.11^2.13

So far, I understand that since the length of the pattern is arbitrarily large (as is the list of primes), I need to use a recursive function to get all the combinations. What I'm really, really stuck is - how to formulate the function's arguments/when to call etc. This is what I've developed so far:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

static const int factors[] = {2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13};
vector<int> vFactors(factors, factors + sizeof(factors) / sizeof(factors[0]));
static const int powers[] = {1, 1, 2, 1};
vector<int> vPowers(powers, powers + sizeof(powers) / sizeof(powers[0]));

// currPIdx [in]  Denotes the index of Power array from which to start generating numbers
// currFidx [in]  Denotes the index of Factor array from which to start generating numbers
vector<int> getNumList(vector<int>& vPowers, vector<int>& vFactors, int currPIdx, int currFIdx)
{
    vector<int> vResult;

    if (currPIdx != vPowers.size() - 1)
    {
        for (int i = currPIdx + 1; i < vPowers.size(); ++i)
        {
            vector<int> vTempResult = getNumList(vPowers, vFactors, i, currFIdx + i);
            vResult.insert(vResult.end(), vTempResult.begin(), vTempResult.end());
        }

        int multFactor = pow((float) vFactors[currFIdx], vPowers[currPIdx]);
        for (int i = 0; i < vResult.size(); ++i)
            vResult[i] *= multFactor;
    }
    else
    {   // Terminating the recursive call
        for (int i = currFIdx; i < vFactors.size(); ++i)
        {
            int element = pow((float) vFactors[i], vPowers[currPIdx]);
            vResult.push_back(element);
        }
    }
    return vResult;
}

int main()
{
    vector<int> vNumList = getNumList(vPowers, vFactors, 0, 0);
    cout << "List of numbers: " << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < vNumList.size(); ++i)
        cout << vNumList[i] << endl;
}
```

When I'm running the above, I'm getting a incorrect list:

```
List of numbers: 
66
78
650
14
22
26
```

I've somehow run into a mental block, as I can't seem to figure out how to appropriately change the last parameter in the recursive call (which I believe is the reason my program isn't working)!!

It would be really great if anyone would be good enough to tweak my code with the missing logic (or even point me to it - I'm not looking for a complete solution!). I would be really grateful if you could restrict your answer to standard C++!

(In case someone notices that I'm missing out permutations of the given pattern, which would lead to other numbers such as 2.3.5.7^2 etc - don't worry, I intend to repeat this algorithm on all possible permutations of the given pattern by using next_permutate!).

PS: Not a homework/interview problem, just a part of an algorithm for a very interesting Project Euler problem (I think you can even guess which one :)).

EDIT: I've solved the problem on my own - which I've posted as an answer. If you like it, do upvote it (I can't accept it as the answer till it gets more votes than the other answer!)...

Answer (score 2):

Forget about factorization for a moment. The problem you want to solve is having two lists P and F and finding all possible pairings (p,f) for p in P and f in F. This means you'll have |P| * |P|-1 ... * |P|-(|F|-1) possible pairings (assigning one from P to the first element of F, leaves |P|-1 possibilities to match the second element etc). You might want to separate that part of the problem in your code. If you recurse that way, the last step is choosing remaining element from P to the last element of F. Does that help? I must admit I don't understand your code well enough to provide an answer tailored to your current state, but that's how I'd approach it in general.

Comment: btw you'll get duplicates because pairing P[0] with F[0] or with F[1] will both times result in 2^1... if you make sure you return a unique list of numbers, that doesn't make the approach incorrect, but not as efficient as it could be. One way to go might be to represent F as {1:3, 2:1} (accounting for the fact that some factors are identical) and adapt that structure as you go into recursion. I|d have to think about that further in fact ;) but my approach might be to first start with a working first solution

Comment: Hi Nicolas, thanks for the answer, but I have to admit I didn't really understand it well enough to tailor my code according to what you suggested, but I got it working anyway! It was a simple DFS tree that I needed to visualize, and I kept thinking up more complex stuff!

Answer (score 1):

Well, I figured out this one on my own! Here's the code for it (which I hope is self-explanatory, but I can clarify in case anyone needs more details):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

static const int factors[] = {2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13};
vector<int> vFactors(factors, factors + sizeof(factors) / sizeof(factors[0]));

static const int powers[] = {1, 1, 2, 1};
vector<int> vPowers(powers, powers + sizeof(powers) / sizeof(powers[0]));

// idx - The index from which the rest of the factors are to be considered. 
//       0 <= idx < Factors.size() - Powers.size()
// lvl - The lvl of the depth-first tree
//       0 <= lvl < Powers.size()
// lvlProd - The product till the previous level for that index.
void generateNumList
(  
    vector<int>& vPowers, 
    vector<int>& vFactors,
    vector<int>& vNumList, 
    int idx, 
    int lvl, 
    long lvlProd
)
{
    // Terminating case
    if (lvl == vPowers.size() - 1)
    {
        long prod = pow((float) vFactors[idx], vPowers[lvl]) * lvlProd;
        vNumList.push_back(prod);
    }
    else
    {
        // Recursive case
        long tempLvlProd = lvlProd * pow((float) vFactors[idx], vPowers[lvl]);
        for (int i = idx + 1; i < vFactors.size(); ++i)
            generateNumList(vPowers, vFactors, vNumList, i, lvl + 1, 
                            tempLvlProd);
    }
}

vector<int> getNumList(vector<int>& vPowers, vector<int>& vFactors)
{
    vector<int> vNumList;
    for (int i = 0; i < vFactors.size(); ++i)
        generateNumList(vPowers, vFactors, vNumList, i, 0, 1);
    return vNumList;
}

int main()
{
    vector<int> vNumList = getNumList(vPowers, vFactors);
    cout << endl << "List of numbers (" << vNumList.size() << ") : " << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < vNumList.size(); ++i)
        cout << vNumList[i] << endl;
}
```

The output of the above code (I had to work really long to get rid of duplicate entries algorithmically! ):

```
List of numbers (15) : 
1050
1650
1950
3234
3822
9438
5390
6370
15730
22022
8085
9555
23595
33033
55055

real    0m0.002s
user    0m0.001s
sys     0m0.001s
```